# how to check sim / WIFI internet is available but not working . how to verify ? In android

Tags: android

```
final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) this .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 
final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI); 
final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE); 
if (wifi.isAvailable()) { 
    return true; 
} 
else if (mobile.isAvailable()) { 
    return true; 
} 
else { 
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check internet access on Android? InetAddress never times out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-times-out)

Comment: simply try requestion some website.

Answer (score 1):

Use Connectivity Manager

```
ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

if ( conMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED 
|| conMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ) {

// you are online

}
else if ( 
conMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED 
|| conMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED) {

// you are not online
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ConnectivityManager    connManager     = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfowifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    NetworkInfo mobile    = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    if (networkInfowifi.isConnected() || mobile.isConnected()) {
```

//write your code

}